# Interpreting meaning of coordinates given a metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I was working problem 3.6 in Carroll's GR textbook and was given the following metric, which

> is a good approximation to the metric outside the surface of the Earth.

$ds^2=-(1+2 \Phi(r))dt^2 + (1-2\Phi(r))dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2)$,

for $\Phi(r)=-GM/r$, where $G$ is Newton's constant and M is the mass of the Earth.

My question is: are we allowed to treat the coordinate $\phi$ as rotating with the Earth *based upon the information given above*?

I know the standard interpretation is to treat fixed points on the Earth as *moving* in $\phi$, so that any point aside from the poles has a non-zero angular velocity $\omega(\phi)$. I was wondering whether this is the only allowed interpretation of this metric and if so why.

Comment: If $\phi=\omega t$ you'll get the Coriolis and centrifugal "forces" in the geodesic equation for a test particle. If you dont want these, $\phi$ cannot be rotating with the Earth.